# How to match one ID from Multiple ID's?

Tags: php, security, matching, verification

I have this script below where it scans users that are allowed to see a post.  How do i update it so that it will match the person viewing's ID to the one stored in the field.  If it matches it works else it doesn't.  The stored entries will be something like 99394david, 324234smith, 34343jane.  So this script i have is not matching it.

```
    $kit = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$sql="SELECT `Who_can_see` from `posts` where `post_id` = '$kit'";  
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    if ($result == "")
    {
    echo "";
    }
    echo "";


    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($rows == 0)
    {
    print("");

    }
    elseif($rows > 0)
    {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $userallowed = htmlspecialchars($row['who_can_see']);
    }
    }

    //$personid is drawn from the database.  its the id of the
     person viewing the link.

    if ( $userallowed == $personid ) {
echo("allowed");
    } else {
echo("not allowed");
    die();
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply add the `$personid` to the query (although I have doubts about how you are filling your `posts` table exactly...):

```
$sql="SELECT `Who_can_see` from `posts`
      where `post_id` = '$kit'
        AND `Who_can_see` = '$personid'";
```

If your result contains a row, the user is allowed to view the post.

By the way, I would also recommend using prepared statements to avoid any potential sql injection problems.

**Edit:** Based on the fact that `Who_can_see` can contain a comma separated list of entries, you can use your original script, and just change how you match, using for example [`stripos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

```
if ( stripos($userallowed, $personid) !== false ) {
    // $personid is found in $userallowed
    echo("allowed");
} else {
    echo("not allowed");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That didn't work.  I am using escape string, that should be enough, no?

Comment: @ariel Yes, that's enough. What do both values look like (`Who_can_see` and `$personid`) exactly for a valid example?

Comment: who_can_see might have everyone, just me or it can be one person like 99394david or multiple people like 99394david, 324234smith, 34343jane

Comment: I believe i needed add a closing }.  I did that but despite that it won't show anything on the screen...

Comment: @ariel You just needed to replace that one line, the ones below it were just to mark clearly in what section. Anyway, can you post the results of `var_dump($userallowed)` and `var_dump($personid)`?

Comment: My bad.  I by mistake had swapped variables.  It works but how do i enhance it so if it does't match it says not allowed?

Comment: Also one thing i just noticed.  If i have a query such as this one how do i allow the person who posted it to view it since he/she will not be in the user_allowed list because they are the ones deciding who sees it.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.  I am new to PHP... thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Can't we do something like if $userallowed, $systemid or if $postingid = $viewing id then allow?

Comment: @ariel Yes, you can add that `OR` condition after the condition you have now.